# How can I add arguments to my bash script called in Java?

Tags: java, linux, bash

i'm trying to find a way to add any number of argument to a bash script called in java language. When I call a script without arguments it works just fine, but the moment I try to add arguments it skips the script and end the application. The **getName** function returns the name of the script.

Here is the function called to execute the script :

```
    String cmd = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()+"/"+getName();
    Process p;

    try{
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh",cmd});
        p.waitFor();
        p.destroy();
    }catch (Exception e) {}
```

And here is where I create the script (I put the function above in the constructor of the Script class)

```
new Script("script_name",new String[]{argument1,argument2});
```

Comment: what do you think `catch (Exception e) {}` does?

Comment: How about ```Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/bin/sh", cmd, argument1, argument2})``` ?

Answer (score 1):

from Javadoc I would change the line to:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh",cmd, argument1,argument2 });
```

It says:

"cmdarray - array containing the command to call and its arguments."

Which means the String array consists of the command and all the parameters.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-